# ESLint: (64:12) Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}" in React Native

Tags: react-native

While styling my react native app, an error is getting displayed repetitively which is unusual because the syntax is absolutely normal and never gave me problem in other apps?

[My full code at expo.](https://snack.expo.io/@vshiva2306/todoapp)

Comment: Please do not post images of your code. Instead, copy-paste the entire code and highlight the part where you are receiving an error. Please see : [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal I have attached my code herein. I hope it is visible now.

Comment: @Shivangi you were asked to copy-paste code to your question. This link may become dead in future (BTW does your error occur there?)

Comment: @barbsan yes. Could you please trace what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two little mistakes.
First one is that you never close `<Note />` tag inside your map function:

```
let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val,key)=>{
  return (<Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val} deleteMethod={()=>this.deleteNote(key)} />);
});
```

Second one is that you have an extra curly bracket at the end of the file, remove it and it should work.

Comment: Are you sure? I modified your snack and it works. I'll try to save changes and share that to you